# match_parent compatibility

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

My application targets the v10 of the android Sdk but has the v6 for minSdkVersion. 
By default the "match_parent" propertie will be used for the width or height. Should i change it for fill_parent to ensure backwards compatibility of device with android under 2.2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you should use fill_parent instead of match_parent to reduce the ambiguity as your min sdk version is V6.
**fill_parent** also works on android 2.2 .

Comment: But will a compiled app that used `match_parent` **fail** to run on an older device (such as an Android 2.1 device)?

Answer (score 2):

Use match_parent. Both [FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT) are compiled to -1 and will work on any Android device.